# Read BitmapData from multiple threads

Tags: c#, bitmap, bitmapdata

I'm having multiple threads that need to READ the same bitmap. They all need to potentially read the entire bitmap.

I want them to access the underlying bytes, so each thread invokes `LockBits` with `ReadOnly` lockmode.

```
BitmapData bits = videoEntry.Data.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

var bytes = new byte[width * height * 4];
Marshal.Copy(bits.Scan0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

videoEntry.Data.UnlockBits(bits);

DoSomethingThreadSpecificWithByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Unfortunately, two consecutive calls to `LockBits` throws an exception `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Bitmap region is already locked.'` Which kind of makes sense, although I only want to read the memory.

My questions:

Is there another/better way to read the bytes of a `Bitmap` from multiple threads?

Obviously, I can preprocess the byte array and let all threads access that, but I guess it's nice to keep the `Bitmap` classes together.

Comment: Do I get this right, that access is read-only?

Comment: Yes, no thread is modifying the bitmap data